# Need mysql join to work without giving duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, join, duplicates

I have two mysql tables like this

1. **hotel_details**

   hotel_id

   hotel_name

   language_id
2. **hotel_descriptions**

   hotel_id

   description

   language_id

the language id can have 0, 1 respectively for english and arabic. There are multiple descriptions in english for the same hotel. And there are multiple descriptions in arabic for the same hotel. Like 10 rows in english for the same hotel id and 10 rows in arabic for the same hotel id.

The hotel in the `hotel_details` table are **unique** and non-repeated.

Now I want to add a join in such a way that I get all the descriptions in the below format.

`hotel_id, hotel_name, english_description, arabic_description.`

And so I should have non-repeated descriptions in english and arabic for the same hotel id. How can I make that possible in MySQL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a `GROUP BY hotel_id`

Comment: That will only return one row from the descriptions table. I need all 10 english rows data and all 10 arabic rows data as well. They all have same hotel id.

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself, if you want all 10 rows but no duplicates, what are you asking for?  If you have 10 descriptions in each language, how are you determining which `english_description` and which `arabic_description` will be grouped  together?

Comment: The issue is that I get 1 english description repeated 10 times with 10 arabic descriptions. Then again I get 2nd english description repeated 10 times with 10 arabic descriptions. So I want the pair to be unique.

Comment: why do you need this forced coupling? as Devon said you have no way to group descriptions together , since you need to apply logic on the results you might as well go for a regular join and apply that logic in your code.

Comment: It may be more clear if you show the query.  Your database design doesn't really make sense to make pairs of multiple descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 pairs of tables as you need to pair the values together.

Essentially what you are doing is matching an english table with an arabic table for the same hotel and then outputing the description from each table.

```
select distinct a.hotel_id, a.hotel_name, c.description, d.description
from hotel_details a
inner join hotel_details b on a.hotel_id = b.hotel_id
                                and a.language_id != b.language_id
inner join hotel_descriptions c on c.hotel_id = b.hotel_id
                                and c.language_id != b.language_id
inner join hotel_descriptions d on d.hotel_id = a.hotel_id
                                and d.language_id != a.language_id
```

The resultant resultset would include duplicates for each of the combinations of hotel records, therefore the DISTINCT is added to the result set to limit it to one set of answers only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT in mysql query..